# Create New Timezone in pytz

Tags: python, pytz

I'm trying to create a timezone object for "GMT+01", however, I haven't been able to find a way to do that using pytz.  I tried using cities that (http://wwp.greenwichmeantime.com/time-zone/gmt-plus-1/) says are in this timezone, but they all give seemingly weird and inconsistent results (they're relative to LMT)

```
>>> timezone('Africa/Algiers')
<DstTzInfo 'Africa/Algiers' PMT+0:09:00 STD>
>>> timezone('Africa/Brazzaville')
<DstTzInfo 'Africa/Brazzaville' LMT+1:01:00 STD>
>>> timezone('Africa/Conakry')
<DstTzInfo 'Africa/Conakry' LMT-1 day, 23:05:00 STD>
>>> timezone('Africa/Douala')
<DstTzInfo 'Africa/Douala' LMT+0:39:00 STD>
```

Does anyone know of a way to just create a custom timezone with "GMT+01" or maybe even creating one relative to timezone("GMT").  I tried adding a datetime.timedelta, but that (unsurprisingly) didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using `pytz` by selecting timezone, then try to manipulate strings and extract from `datetime` the time in function of GMT, then you can select only time with `GMT+x` in your case, it's `GMT+1`

```
import pytz

from datetime import tzinfo, timedelta, datetime

GMT_1_Time_Zone = []
for tz in pytz.common_timezones:
    now = datetime.now(pytz.timezone(tz))
    print now
    if "+0100" in now.strftime("%z"):
        GMT_1_Time_Zone.append((tz, "(GMT%s) %s" % (now.strftime("%z"), tz)))


print GMT_1_Time_Zone
```

Output:

> [('Africa/Algiers', '(GMT+0100) Africa/Algiers'), ('Africa/Bangui',
>   '(GMT+0100) Africa/Bangui'), ('Africa/Brazzaville', '(GMT+0100)
>   Africa/Brazzaville'), ('Africa/Ceuta', '(GMT+0100) Africa/Ceuta'),
>   ('Africa/Douala', '(GMT+0100) Africa/Douala'), ('Africa/Kinshasa',
>   '(GMT+0100) Africa/Kinshasa'), ('Africa/Lagos', '(GMT+0100)
>   Africa/Lagos'), ('Africa/Libreville', '(GMT+0100) Africa/Libreville'),
>   ('Africa/Luanda', '(GMT+0100) Africa/Luanda'), ('Africa/Malabo',
>   '(GMT+0100) Africa/Malabo'), ('Africa/Ndjamena', '(GMT+0100)
>   Africa/Ndjamena'), ('Africa/Niamey', '(GMT+0100) Africa/Niamey'),
>   ('Africa/Porto-Novo', '(GMT+0100) Africa/Porto-Novo'),
>   ('Africa/Tripoli', '(GMT+0100) Africa/Tripoli'), ('Africa/Tunis',
>   '(GMT+0100) Africa/Tunis'), ('Arctic/Longyearbyen', '(GMT+0100)
>   Arctic/Longyearbyen'), ('Europe/Amsterdam', '(GMT+0100)
>   Europe/Amsterdam'), ('Europe/Andorra', '(GMT+0100) Europe/Andorra'),
>   ('Europe/Belgrade', '(GMT+0100) Europe/Belgrade'), ('Europe/Berlin',
>   '(GMT+0100) Europe/Berlin'), ('Europe/Bratislava', '(GMT+0100)
>   Europe/Bratislava'), ('Europe/Brussels', '(GMT+0100)
>   Europe/Brussels'), ('Europe/Budapest', '(GMT+0100) Europe/Budapest'),
>   ('Europe/Busingen', '(GMT+0100) Europe/Busingen'),
>   ('Europe/Copenhagen', '(GMT+0100) Europe/Copenhagen'),
>   ('Europe/Gibraltar', '(GMT+0100) Europe/Gibraltar'),
>   ('Europe/Ljubljana', '(GMT+0100) Europe/Ljubljana'),
>   ('Europe/Luxembourg', '(GMT+0100) Europe/Luxembourg'),
>   ('Europe/Madrid', '(GMT+0100) Europe/Madrid'), ('Europe/Malta',
>   '(GMT+0100) Europe/Malta'), ('Europe/Monaco', '(GMT+0100)
>   Europe/Monaco'), ('Europe/Oslo', '(GMT+0100) Europe/Oslo'),
>   ('Europe/Paris', '(GMT+0100) Europe/Paris'), ('Europe/Podgorica',
>   '(GMT+0100) Europe/Podgorica'), ('Europe/Prague', '(GMT+0100)
>   Europe/Prague'), ('Europe/Rome', '(GMT+0100) Europe/Rome'),
>   ('Europe/San_Marino', '(GMT+0100) Europe/San_Marino'),
>   ('Europe/Sarajevo', '(GMT+0100) Europe/Sarajevo'), ('Europe/Skopje',
>   '(GMT+0100) Europe/Skopje'), ('Europe/Stockholm', '(GMT+0100)
>   Europe/Stockholm'), ('Europe/Tirane', '(GMT+0100) Europe/Tirane'),
>   ('Europe/Vaduz', '(GMT+0100) Europe/Vaduz'), ('Europe/Vatican',
>   '(GMT+0100) Europe/Vatican'), ('Europe/Vienna', '(GMT+0100)
>   Europe/Vienna'), ('Europe/Warsaw', '(GMT+0100) Europe/Warsaw'),
>   ('Europe/Zagreb', '(GMT+0100) Europe/Zagreb'), ('Europe/Zurich',
>   '(GMT+0100) Europe/Zurich')]

**UPDATE**

After digging in the problem. I found two better solutions to do that.

```
from dateutil import tz
import datetime
import pytz

from datetime import datetime
dt = datetime.strptime("2014-11-02 21:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
dt = pytz.timezone('Etc/GMT+1').localize(dt)
dt.isoformat()
print dt
```

using `parser`

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
dt = parse("2014-11-02 21:00:00" + "GMT+0100")
dt.isoformat()
print dt
```

Comment: this looks like the right answer.  Out of curiosity, why the string addition in parse?  Was it just to make it clearer?  Seems to work without it.