# Localise pandas timestamps with no DST transistion

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to import CSV data from a file produced by a device which has a system clock which is set to `'Australia/Adelaide'` time, but doesn't switch from standard to daylight time in summer. I can import it no problem as `tz-naive` but I need to correlate it with data which is `tz-aware`.

The following is incorrect as it assumes the data transitions to summer time on '2017-10-01'

```
data = pd.read_csv('~/dev/datasets/data.csv', parse_dates=['timestamp'], index_col=['timestamp'])
data.index.tz_localize('Australia/Adelaide')
```

`tz_localize` contains a number of arguments to deal with ambiguous dates - but I don't see any way to tell it that the data doesn't transition at all. Is there a way to specify a "custom" timezone that's `'Australia/Adelaide', no daylight savings`?

Edit: I found this question - [Create New Timezone in pytz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26742896/create-new-timezone-in-pytz) which has given me some ideas - in this case the timestamps are a constant offset from UTC so i can probably add that to the date after importing, localise as UTC then convert to 'Australia/Adelaide'. I'll report back...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came up with is as follows:

Since the data is 'Australia/Adelaide' with no DLS transistion, that means the UTC offset is a constant (+10:30) all year. Hence a solution is to import that data as `tz-naive`, subtract 10 hours and 30 minutes, localise as UTC then convert to 'Australia/Adelaide', i.e.

```
data = pd.read_csv('~/dev/datasets/data.csv', parse_dates=['timestamp'], index_col=['timestamp'])
data.index = data.index - pd.DateOffset(hours=10) - pd.DateOffset(minutes=30)
data.index = data.index.tz_localize('UTC').tz_convert('Australia/Adelaide')
```